# Guidance for C++ / Python developer to understand the web dev world

Tags: frontend, backend, web-development-server

I am programming since quite some years now.
Until now I was mainly focused on writing "normal" applications which run inside a console or with a GUI, sometimes also applications which interact with hardware components such as sensors / actors / ...
During this time I got to know a lot of cool programming principles and tools such as object orientation, modularization, unit-testing, test-driven-development, desing-patterns, code-analysis, ..

Also I have some first experience with hosting a wordpress blog, running static web-sites on a nginx webserver, and writing some small php-forms. But I feel like there is still too much magic in all these web-development topics. And I would like to fill this gap and learn a bit more about all these connected scripting / programming languages and technologies. (Because I hate, when I don't understand how things are working :D :D )
I started with some online "Web-development bootcamp" course at udemy to get a rough overview. This took quite some days now and I think HTML, CSS and Javascript for DOM manipulation / animations are clear to me now. Also I heard a lot about NodeJS and all it's derivate languages and databases like Mongo-DB. But still I feel like there is a lot of things unclear to me.

To get to a better understanding I wanted to development some small web-application. Nothing very special, just some website where you have to login to, are able to generate some data and this data is then persisted into a database and once you login again you are able to see the data again.
I first started with developing some classes in Javascript to represent the data in the browser while you are logged in. But I very soon realized that the Javascript which can run inside the browser is very limited and already for unit-testing and modularization into separate files that include each other I actually needed to do some crazy work-arounds or use other server-side languages like nodejs / php / ... .
After some time coding I decided to take one step back, trying to understand the basic design patterns of web-applications and not running for a long time into the wrong direction.

My questions are:

- Is there some typical way to go / best practice while developing web-applications?
- What are the typical key players? I know there is the difference between front-end, back-end and databases.
- But are there some do's and don't's that good WebDev's follow?
  For example:

  - which code is usually written in back-end / server-side languages?
  - What is usually done in the front-end? (Only desing and animations?)
  - Do I have to move all business logic into the back-end, also for security reasons or is this maybe also a bad idea because of peformance reasons?
  - What programming languages are more or less dead and not to be used in the future?
  - What things are typically reused from frameworks, for example authentication and session handling?

Also I felt like some things I know from other programming languages are not so easy in languages like javascript / nodejs. I am willing to spend time and effort into learning all these things but I would also like to keep the quality standards that I know from C++ /
Python. On the other side I also wondered if these patterns that I have in my head are maybe just boundaries that are completely useless in modern web-development? (e.g. typing, object orientation, modularization / splitting the code to be very reusable )

What do you think am I on the wrong track here, or do I maybe simply use the wrong languages?

I hope the long text is not knocking everyone down / keeping everyone from answering me :o
I would really appreciate your help and guidance to understand everything a bit better and to not repeat the things already a lot of others have done wrong ;)

BR, mezorian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, most of the questions are very opionated (at least the answers are) and your question will probably be closed for that reason. So I will post my answer before completing it and expand on it after.

First off a good roadmap to become a web developer. I like it mainly because it shows the crazyness the web development world has come to (don't be shocked!): https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-2020-web-developer-roadmap-76503ddfb327

---

Trying to answer some of your question (answers are my opinion):

> Is there some typical way to go / best practice while developing web-applications?

I'm tempted to say there are as many ways to do web development as there are web-developers in the world, but that might be a bit exaggerated. If you want some guidelines, I'd pick one of the major web frameworks and learn the way they do web development. With web frameworks I mean all kinds of frameworks starting with JS-frameworks all the way to static site generators, etc. They all have their ecosystem and their own rules.

> What are the typical key players? I know there is the difference between front-end, back-end and databases.

(personal opinion) I work with Go in the backend. I love it because it brings back some simplicity in the crazy world of choices being a web developer. Since you know C, Go will probably be easy for you. It has static typing, structs, etc, but no need to manually manage your memory. It is also much faster than most other backend languages used in web development (Python, NodeJS, PHP, Ruby, etc).

In the front-end I have used native JS, jQuery, React, Vue, etc. I'm still waiting for something that makes things easy again. Flutter seems to be something that has a good approach, but is not really a web front framework (yet). (Don't do public websites with Flutter! They are not indexable.) We'll see where it goes.

Databases I will not go into here as that is another huge topic. Let's just say that I'm more a fan of using multiple databases for their specific strengths rather than a big one that is supposed to be good at anything.

> which code is usually written in back-end / server-side languages?

Even this depends largely on your choices (framework and preference). One thing for sure has to be in the backend and that is security related stuff. Anything you put in frontend code is visible to an experienced user.

Apart from that there are some ecosystems where you don't write any backend code but talk to a (cloud) service that is basically like a database with a web endpoint on top with secured login. (for example https://firebase.google.com/.) Here the security related stuff is baked into the service.

If you do both, keeping business logic in the backend is probably a good idea. If the frontend calculates something (for quick response), the backend should double check that (e.g. calculating the total in a cart). But this is too general. There can always be use cases where some business logic needs to be implemented in the front-end.

> Do I have to move all business logic into the back-end, also for security reasons or is this maybe also a bad idea because of performance reasons?

Performance can be a problem, but mostly because the roundtrip time to the server and back. If you do that for every tiny information, the UI will become sluggish. You might want to think about doing e.g. a calculation client-side.

JS-Frameworks like React, Vue don't request html from the backend, but data and build the html based on that data client-side. I'd use them if I have a very data driven website / webapp, especially if it is user-dependent. Transferring only the data and building the html for every site from it in the browser based on user settings and data, saves a lot of roundtrips.

If you are worried about server performance: For the server to hit its limit, you'd need heavy usage of your website for that to become an issue (at least with Go). If you get there you can still use horizontal scaling (multiple instances of you server) to solve that. Unless you are working for a large company with millions of users daily, I'd not worry about scaling for now.

> What programming languages are more or less dead and not to be used in the future?

Warning: Very opionated!

I'd say PHP is dead. Many headhunters I've spoken with agree with me. Companies are desperately looking for PHP developers, because many developers are moving on from PHP to something "cooler". You'll definitely find a job with PHP, but might not be so happy with your job. For me it is also a sign of how modern a company really is (if PHP is not it's main backend language (any more)).

Python currently has a big boom. Mostly because of AI development. I'm not sure if that boom is also in the web development, but I'd say not. I used Python before Go (5+ years ago) and before that PHP (8+ years ago). I rarely get Python web developer job offers (at least compared to PHP and Go).

Go is the language of the cloud. It is perfect for concurrent programming which is an essential part in web development (every http call should be handled concurrently). It is fast and light weight and doesn't need anything installed on the server to run (compiles to a single binary without dependencies).

NodeJS: Haven't used. I'm not a fan of Javascript (but it was (and kind of still is) the only option in the browser), so I never liked the idea of using it also in the backend.

TypeScript: might be an alternative to JavaScript (thinking of frontend here) if you like a more structured language.

---

It sounded like you want to build a user baser web app with data being managed by each user. This is what I would (probably) do in that case:

- Backend in Go
- Go serves static files (start html, css, js, images, etc.)
- Go server has an api endpoint that serves data (e.g. REST style)
- Vue (or React) in the frontend
- Vue requests data from the api to build the user-specific content

Comment: Hi @TehSphinX, 
I cannot say how much your super super detailed reply helped me today. 
So first of all thank you very very very much. Some days ago I was very frustrated and confused by the (you call it) "crazyness the web development world has come to". A lot of things were not working as I expected it and I really needed some bigger picture in my head to get an overview. After reading your text I now have this bigger picture :) 
I now have a better idea how to start and spend my day comparing different back-end languages. 
...... to be continued in the next comment ;)

Comment: ........
This comparison and also your recommendation in the last part of your reply motivated me to have a deeper look into the Go-Language. I will now do some online training for Go and try to develop some first simple web-server with it. 
I am sure there will be a lot more questions coming up, but for now your reply answered all questions that I had in my head.
So once again --> Thank you very much for your good guidance! 
It really helped me a lot! 
BR, mezorian

Comment: Once you've done your first steps in Go, this will help you build a good foundation for the web server: https://pace.dev/blog/2018/05/09/how-I-write-http-services-after-eight-years.html